# Beginning Drupal development

Tags: drupal-7

I'm beginning a Drupal development and I have some questions.

1. If I build a site from my localhost and then move it to the production server, do I have to install Drupal on that server or is it enough to move all media, html, php, js files and database to the server?
2. If I have to update a site which has not been done by Drupal but has for example a large SQL-database and discussion forum, how can I copy them from the server to my localhost and integrate them to Drupal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1-> you will need to install Drupal on the server to be sure that all the 'dependencies' are present.

2-> you will need to download the "source code" and dump the database. And copy them to your localhost.